# How could I add a dateformat of dd-mm-yy with my script of jQuery datepicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I tried adding `dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy"`,
but then the rest of the functions just don't work.
Then I tried to change the format globally,

```
 $.datepicker.setDefaults({dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'});
```

But it didn't work either.
I am using jquery-1.9.1, and jquery-ui-1.10.3.

```
$(document).ready(function formUi() {
    var dateToday = new Date();
    $("#datepicker-round-trip-1").datepicker({
        numberOfMonths: 2,
        showButtonPanel: true,
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        inline: true,
        maxDate: new Date(new Date($('datepicker-round-trip-2').val()).valueOf()),
        beforeShow: function () {
            if ($("#datepicker-round-trip-1").val() == "" && $("#datepicker-round-trip-2").val() == "") {
                $("#datepicker-round-trip-1").datepicker('option', { minDate: dateToday, maxDate: null });
            }
            else {
              $("#datepicker-round-trip-1").datepicker('option', { minDate: dateToday });
            }
        },
        onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
            var currentDate = new Date(dateText);
            var valueofcurrentDate = currentDate.valueOf();
            var newDate = new Date(valueofcurrentDate);
            $("#datepicker-round-trip-2").datepicker("option", "minDate", newDate);
        }
    });

    $("#datepicker-round-trip-2").datepicker({
        numberOfMonths: 2,
        showButtonPanel: true,
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        inline: true,
        minDate: new Date(new Date($('#datepicker-round-trip-2').val()).valueOf()),
        beforeShow: function () {
            if ($("#datepicker-round-trip-1").val() == "" && $("#datepicker-round-trip-2").val() == "") {
                $("#datepicker-round-trip-2").datepicker('option', { minDate: dateToday, maxDate: null });
            }
        },
        onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
            var currentDate = new Date(dateText);
            var valueofcurrentDate = currentDate.valueOf();
            var newDate = new Date(valueofcurrentDate);
            $("datepicker-round-trip-1").datepicker("option", "maxDate", newDate);
        }
    });
});
```

The script just sets the datepicker's minDate to the last date selected in the previous date picker. Any help or guidance is appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/MXstJ/ **or** http://jsfiddle.net/gc4nM/

Helpful link: http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Hope this fits your cause `:)`

**Code**

```
$('#z').datepicker({
    inline: true,
    altField: '#d',
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
    defaultDate: new Date()
});
```

Comment: what is altField for ?? i have tried dateFormat it doesn't work though

Comment: @cyber_alchemist `altField` is alternative field: http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#alt-field seems to be working saweet in Jsfiddle, check out your JQ version and thing bro `:)` lemme know how it goes!